# ASP.Net Core 2.1 with OpenID Connect: Correlation state property not found error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, openid-connect

I'm working on a APS.Net Core 2.1 MVC app with OpenID connect using Authorization flow. When running the following configuration I get the error below. I've attempted to specify a redirect uri and change the fields in addauthentication with no success. Find my startup.cs below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        //{
        //    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        //    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        //});

        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options => {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Location"] = "<host url>";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oicd", options =>
        {
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.ClientId = "<client id>";
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.CallbackPath = "/";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Authority = "<authority url>";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Scope.Clear();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        });

        //app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

But get the following error:

```
warn: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[14]
  .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
 System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. 
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
```

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically change the redirect url.  You'd change it dynamically in the Notifications property of the OIDC middleware -- look at the `RedirectingToIdentityprovider` callback and the notification param's Protocol property :

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
{

    n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "YourUrl";   
    await Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[14]
>     .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.

Do you have more than one OIDC handler in DI and you don't set a unique callback path for each of them ? Also try the url with https if you are using http url .